# Problemas al mostrar un boton con django

Tags: python, bootstrap, django, aplicación-web

estoy haciendo un curso de django y llegamos a la parte de crear la tienda online, todo bien hasta que llega la hora de poner los articulos solo se me suma el valor en la variable global sin poner el articulo en el carro de compra ni dejando quitarlo dejo las urls del carro, parte del codigo htlm de la tienda y la construccion del carro porque la verdad no tengo ni idea de que hacer

Urls carro

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name="carro"
urlpatterns = [
path("agregar/<int:producto_id>/", views.agregar, name="agregar"),
path("eliminacion_total/<int:producto_id>/", views.Eliminacion_Total, 
name="eliminacion_total"),
path("restar_producto/<int:producto_id>/", views.Restar, name="restar_producto"),
path("limpiar_carro/", views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar_carro"),
]
```

htlm de el widget

```
{% if request.session.carro.items %}
            {% for key, value in request.session.carro.items %}
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td>{{ value.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.cantidad }}</td>
                    <td>
                     <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' value.producto.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">+</a>
                     <a href="{% url 'carro:restar_producto' value.producto.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">-</a><br/>
                      {{ value.precio }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color: aliceblue;">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                        No hay productos en el carro
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
```

htlm de la tienda

```
 {% extends "GestionGeneralWeb/Base" %}
  {% load static %}
  
  {% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div style="right: auto;">
      <p style="color: aliceblue;"></p>
      {% include "carro/widget" %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      {% for A in P %}
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
          <img src="{{ A.imagen.url }}" alt="Imagen" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">{{ A.nombre }}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ A.precio }} $</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-center">
            <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' A.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo del carro

```
class carro_Compra:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.session = request.session
        self.carro = self.session.get("CarroCompra", {})
    
    def agregar(self, producto):
        if str(producto.id) not in self.carro:
            self.carro[str(producto.id)] = {
                "producto.id": producto.id,
                "nombre": producto.nombre,
                "precio": str(producto.precio),
                "cantidad": 1,
                "imagen": producto.imagen.url
            }
        else:
            for key, value in self.carro.items():
                if key == str(producto.id):
                    value["cantidad"] += 1
                    break
        self.guardar_carro()
        
    def guardar_carro(self):
        self.session["CarroCompra"] = self.carro
        self.session.modified = True
    
    def eliminacion_total(self, producto):
        producto_id = str(producto.id)
        if producto_id in self.carro:
            del self.carro[producto_id]
            self.guardar_carro()
    
    def restar_producto(self, producto):
        producto_id = str(producto.id)
        for key, value in self.carro.items():
            if key == producto_id:
                value["cantidad"] -= 1
                if value["cantidad"] < 1:
                    self.eliminacion_total(producto)
                break
        self.guardar_carro()
    
    def limpiar_carro(self):
        self.session["CarroCompra"] = {}
        self.session.modified = True
```

queria algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero esto es lo que me sale despues de poner todo el codigo para los botones, ya añadiendo algunos productos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]